# Register shutDownHook in web application

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, web, ioc-container

How we can registerShutdown hook in web application?

Is there any whays to register it in web.xml or in applicationContext.xml?

I know that if we are using application with main class it's simple.

```
ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("ApplicationContext.xml");
    context.registerShutdownHook();
```

But what about web application? As it uses ContextListener

Comment: Have you got any solution ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**registerShutdownHook() in standalone (non-web) application:**

The `@PreDestroy` annotation is used on bean method to be notified when the bean is being removed from the context or when the context is shutting down.

Shut down event is fired when `context.close()` or `context.registerShutdownHook()` is invoked.

```
@Component(value="someBean")
public class SomeBean {

    @PreDestroy
    public void destroy() {
        System.out.println("Im inside destroy...");
    }
}
```

I hope you already know this.

---

**registerShutdownHook() in web application:**

In a web application, DispatcherServlet/ContextListener creates the ApplicationContext and it will close the context when the server shutdown. You **don't** need to explicitly invoke `context.close()` or `context.registerShutdownHook()`.

When the server shutdown, `@PreDestory` methods on your bean will be notified automatically.

Comment: Excellent response. The @PreDestroy was the key! Thanks a lot :-)

Comment: @Kalyan :: @ Predestroy is called for Bean destruction, that means if the bean is not singleton this would be invoked multiple times whenever the container removes the bean.

Comment: @Anandj.Kadhi that's not true - http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes-prototype

Answer (score 5):

In web applications, you can use a [`ServletContextListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) which fires when your application is deployed and undeployed:

```
public class MyServletContextListener implements ServletContextListener {
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        //application is being deployed
    }
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        //application is being undeployed
    }
}
```

You can access to your Spring beans by retrieving the current Spring context:

```
public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {
    ServletContext ctx = sce.getServletContext();
    WebApplicationContext springContext = WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(ctx);
    //retrieve your Spring beans here...
    SomeSpringBean bean = (SomeSpringBean)ctx.getBean("someSprinbgBean");
    //...
}
```

Comment: Thank you, for answer. Could you tell, how I can get object that stands for SPRING context. On which I can call context.registerShutdownHook();

Comment: Use can use @PreDestroy method in bean.

Comment: @Javakid that won't work if you want to only fire a process when the application is being undeployed.

Comment: @Luiggi Thanks. Why do you think it wouldn't work and when do you think `@PreDestory` will be invoked? I just tried to stop and undeploy the application, the method gets notified.

Comment: @Javakid try changing the scope of the bean to `prototype` and retrieve it two or more times.

Comment: :) Sorry, but you still didn't give an explanation. ServletContextListener  is used for global cleanup task and @PreDestroy is used for bean specific cleanup task. You can choose either of them depending on your need. When using `prototype`, @PreDestroy will be invoked whenever the bean is removed from the context. Not many people I know use `prototype` correctly. So I can't say how you meant to use it. Anyway I'll leave it here.

Comment: @Javakid I don't need to give an explanation if you understand what will happen with beans as prototype: the process will be invoked per instance removed from the context. And people don't use `prototype` (correctly or not) mainly because the default scope for beans is `singleton`. Since OP haven't provided a way the process should behave nor any scenario for it, this can be the best option. Maybe the clean-up process needs several beans and an orchestration of these.

Comment: I kindly like to let you know that I don't agree with stmt `Maybe the clean-up process needs several beans and an orchestration of these`. That means you are not following Separation of concern law. Each bean should perform its own cleanup task. However, there may be an extreme scenario where global cleanup task might be required.

Comment: @Javakid when maintaining legacy applications, specially very old applications, there's no separation of concern law (just look at a monolithic architecture the application has), so this is the available option. The only thing I'm sure here is that this is the safest approach in case you want a single specific place to fire any clean up process in general web applications. Framework specific benefits (or backdoors to your own doom) are not covered in my answer, and it's good to know about `@PreDestruct` for this case. Just to note, `@PreDestruct` is not from Spring but from Java EE.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. Although @PreDestory is from Java EE, it is very much part of Spring annotation. There is a reason for not introducing new annotation for XML "destroy" attribute alternative and Spring community decided to use the existing annotation in Java EE.

Comment: @Javakid that wasn't the meaning of the last sentence of my comment. Anyway, looks like we both know what we're doing. Hopefully, OP will understand and decide the best option as well :)

Comment: +1 for your effort lol... Have a good night...:) The last message went away before I could finish.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But this approach is not working. I added necessary function @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        ServletContext context = sce.getServletContext();
        WebApplicationContext springContext = WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(context);
        ClassPathXmlApplicationContext applicationContext = (ClassPathXmlApplicationContext) springContext.getParent();
        applicationContext.registerShutdownHook();
    }
 But when I call applicationContext.registerShutDownHook().I got NullPointer excaption

Comment: I think i am missing to do this "In order to receive these notification events, the implementation class must be either declared in the deployment descriptor of the web application, annotated with WebListener, or registered via one of the addListener methods defined on ServletContext."

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Your Solution is working, i have missed adding entry in the web.xml :(  Thank you!! very much.

Comment: Is there a way only calling PreDestroy, because PostConstruct is called by ServletContextListener, but getting NPE because of; some of fields are not autowired at that time. Please help.

Comment: @KanagaveluSugumar Spring will wire everything for you. If something cannot be wired is because it was lazy wiring or the bean couldn't been created, and you have to check why wasn't created.

Comment: In your code sample given the variable `springContext` is null we are getting. This is same even @slisnychyi mentioned in this comment section. Also there is TYPO in the sample  `ctx.getBean()` should `springContext.getBean()`

Answer (score 2):

Using Spring 3+ you can add a ContextCleanupListener to the application context.

Register your listener at startup like so (you might prefer to use xml config but the same applies)

```
package com.myapp

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRegistration;

import org.springframework.web.WebApplicationInitializer;
import org.springframework.web.context.ContextCleanupListener;
import org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener;
import org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet;

public class MyWebApplicationInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext)
            throws ServletException {
        WebApplicationContext appContext = getContext();


        servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(appContext));

        // line adding an implementation of ContextCleanupListener
        servletContext.addListener(new MyWebApplicationCleanupListener());

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = servletContext.addServlet("DispatcherServlet", new DispatcherServlet(appContext));
            dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
            dispatcher.addMapping("/");
    }

    private AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext getContext() { 
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        context.setConfigLocation("com.myapp");
        return context;
    }
}
```

**Implementation of ContextCleanupListener that runs your shutdown code:**

```
package com.myapp;

import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent;
import com.myapp.resources.requiring.clean.shutdown
import org.springframework.web.context.ContextCleanupListener;

public class MyWebApplicationCleanupListener extends ContextCleanupListener {

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event) {
        // put your shutdown code in here

        MyResourceNeedingShutdown dataStore = MyResourceNeedingShutdown.getInstance();
        dataStore.shutdown();
    }

}
```

When you run up say tomcat for example, and press CTRL + C to shut it down, you'll immediately see the contextDestroyed method be hit in the debugger if you put a breakpoint there.

Answer (score 0):

@Luiggi Mendoza answer is started working when i add entry in web.xml.

```
<web-app ...>
   <listener>
    <listener-class>
             com....MyServletContextListener
        </listener-class>
   </listener>
</web-app>
```

you can see the stack trace of initialising/notifying the listener object by the tomcat; which is much before spring does.

```
com....MyServletContextListener.init(nothing but calling @PostConstruct)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.postConstruct(DefaultInstanceManager.java:203)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.postConstruct(DefaultInstanceManager.java:188)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:143)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4649)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5189)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:724)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:700)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:952)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1823)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

But important thing is @PreDestroy called first by Spring, then after contextDestroyed is called and again @PreDestroy called by non-spring thread.

So if you want to complete some work; on that time if you want to ensure other resource thread are available then hold this @PreDestroy.

```
@PreDestroy
public void cleanup() {
    eventTaskExecutor.shutdown();
    try {
        /**
         * This is blocking call to avoid other threads (like logger demon thread)
         * not closed before this completes the job. Else worker thread cannot log
         * event.
         * 
         * This will be the case when thread is busy in getting the web response,
         * better will wait for that, and log the web response.
         * 
         */
        eventTaskExecutor.awaitTermination(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   
}
```

Just know that the below is one more way of getting the @postConstruct hook within the class.

```
@Autowired
public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
    applicationContext.getBean("myRelatedClass", MyRelatedClass.class);
}
```

One more thing is @PreDestroy is called only for singleton objects not available for prototype objects.