# Spring Boot @PreDestroy annotation not working

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm new to Spring Boot, and I've got a Spring Boot application that seems to be ignoring the @PreDestroy annotation - when I run from command line or via Eclipse, I'm never seeing the @PreDestroy code being run when application is shutdown (e.g. via ctrl-c)

Code is below ...

Application.java:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    @Autowired
    private MessageProcessor messageProcessor;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {    
        messageProcessor.run();
    }

}
```

Message Processor Config:

```
@Configuration
public class MessageProcessorConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public MessageProcessor messageProcessor() {
        return new MessageProcessorImpl();
    }
}
```

Message Processor:

```
public class MessageProcessorImpl implements MessageProcessor {

    @Override
    public void run() {

        while (isActive()) {
           …
        }
    }


   @PreDestroy
   public void shutdown() { 
       System.out.println("MessageProcessorImpl - shutting down");
   }

}
```

Comment: The PreDestroy annotation is used on methods as a callback notification to signal that the instance is in the process of being **removed** by the **container**, it is not a Pre-Shuttdown of your application

Comment: So @PreDestroy will not fire when I use ctrl-c or kill <pid> on the running application? Is there something I can to to catch this event ?

Comment: look at this question  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23936162/register-shutdownhook-in-web-application

Comment: Reading that, it looks like @PreDestroy should be being called ...

Comment: No, if the bean is not **singleton** this would be invoked multiple times

Comment: OK, do you know how I should capture the shutdown event then? - Thanks

Comment: maybe you need to look at **ContextClosedEvent** https://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/event_handling_in_spring.htm, but i didn't try it

Comment: @AzzabiHaythem Ok, but finbin's bean is a singleton, as all beans are singletons by default. So why is PreDestroy not called?

Comment: Because the application is already broken, the application cannot prevent and see the future(PreDestroy focus on beans and not on the application)

Answer (score 4):

The @PreDestroy **does not work**  when the `Scope(value=ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)` is used on the bean since the bean's spawned with this method is not completely managed by the IOC container.

The @PreDestroy works when the `Scope(value=ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_SINGLETON)` is used on the bean.

Comment: could you link some source please?

Comment: Did not work for me with Spring Boot 2.4.3

Answer (score 3):

Spring Boot register shutdown hook during context creation
see `org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext#registerShutdownHook`method. 
As result context must be closed on *crtl+c* combination (if you run your app through `java -jar app.jar` cmd) and which in turn triggers your *@Predestroy* method. This works for me.

I don't see any remarks in your code. I can suggest annotating your `MessageProcessorImpl` bean with @Component annotation instead of a manual *@Bean* declaration.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding this line in your xml.

```
<bean class="org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />
```

Comment: <bean class="org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />

Comment: please add your comment in the body of your answer and also add some comments regarding how it helps to solve the problem in question.

Comment: Hello @user12059843. You can still [edit] your answer, and add that line to it.

Answer (score -1):

The `@PreDestroy` will not be called because the application is not fully initialized yet. This is due the usage of the `@PostConstruct` on the init method, which is called as part of the initializing of Spring.

This can be fixed by using the [CommandLineRunner](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/CommandLineRunner.html), which is called after Spring is fully initialized:

```java
@Component
public class Initializer implements CommandLineRunner {

    private final private MessageProcessor messageProcessor;

   public Initializer(MessageProcessor messageProcessor) {
       this.messageProcessor = messageProcessor;

    @Override
    public void run(String[] args) {
        messageProcessor.init();
    }
}
```